# How To apply independence to $X^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let A and B be 2 independent random variables that are positive and have a variance that is not zero. Prove that $A^2$ and $B$ are independent.

What I know so far:

if $A \perp B$ then $Pr[A=a \cap B=b]= Pr[A=a] *Pr[B=b]$. Since we know that A is positive then all the values in f(A) must be positive. How can I use this knowledge to prove that $Pr[A^2=a \cap B=b]= Pr[A^2=a] *Pr[B=b]$? I tried to figure out how to determine the probability $X^2$ or $Pr[X^2=x]$ in terms of $X$. I've been stuck on this and don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what the desired answer is without knowing the definition you are using for independent. It certainly seems suspicious that they are asking you to assume that the random variables are positive and have nonzero variance, since that is not required at all for the result to hold. In fact, if $A$ and $B$ are independent random variables and $f$ and $g$ are any (measurable) functions, then $f(A)$ and $g(B)$ are independent. So this problem is just the special case of $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x.$ How to prove this fact depends a lot on the specifics definitions you're using, though.

But the fact that they are asking you to assume the random variable is positive here, and that you've been given $P(A=a\land B=b) = P(A=a)P(B=b)$ suggests that your approach of trying to get $P(A^2=a)$ in terms of $A$ may be what they're looking for. Observe that since $A^2$ is positive, it’s only nonzero if $a$ is positive, in which case, $A^2 = a$ means the same thing as $A = \sqrt{a}.$ Thus, $$P(A^2 = a\land B = b) = P( A=\sqrt{a}\land B = b) = P( A = \sqrt{a} )P( B = b) = P(A^2=a)P(B=b).$$

I'll emphasize again, though: this is putting the cart before the horse a bit. This problem is really just a special case of the idea that events pertaining to independent random variables are independent. This is something that should accord with the intuitive idea of independent variables as carrying no information about each other, and it's an important thing to remember and use to build your intuition.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you deduced this? I'd like to understand why this is  the answer, thanks!

Comment: @andydandy elaborated

Comment: In this problem independence is defined that if $A \perp B$ then $Pr[A=a \cap B=b]= Pr[A=a] *Pr[B=b]$

Comment: @andydandy ok, I guess you are only studying discrete distributions then? I think in that case that the answer I gave is what was intended. You can also show it in general (not assuming $A$ is positive), but it’s a bit of work. (But the assumption of nonzero variance still seems irrelevant to me.)